# Copying 2 files into a path of the current user profile

Tags: variables, deployment, vbscript, file-copying

I am trying to copy a couple of files in the following path:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin

I am using VBS and the script I am using is as follows:

```
DestinationFile1 = ("C:\Users" + Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin\adobeconnectaddin.exe")
DestinationFile2 = ("C:\Users" + Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin\digest.s")
SourceFile1 = "adobeconnectaddin.exe"
SourceFile2 = "digest.s"
path=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
DestinationPath = ("C:\Users" + path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin")
Dim objNetwork
Dim userName
Dim FSO
Dim Folder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = objNetwork.userName
If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia")) Then


    FSO.CreateFolder(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia")
End If
If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player")) Then
    ' Delete this if you don't want the MsgBox to show
    'MsgBox("Local folder doesn't exists, creating...")

    ' Create folder
    'MsgBox("C:\" + splitString(2) + "\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client")
    FSO.CreateFolder(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player")
End If
If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com")) Then
    ' Delete this if you don't want the MsgBox to show
    'MsgBox("Local folder doesn't exists, creating...")

    ' Create folder
    'MsgBox("C:\" + splitString(2) + "\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile")
    FSO.CreateFolder(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com")
End If
If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin")) Then
    ' Delete this if you don't want the MsgBox to show
    'MsgBox("Local folder doesn't exists, creating...")

    ' Create folder
    'MsgBox("C:\" + splitString(2) + "\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile")
    FSO.CreateFolder(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin")
End If
If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin")) Then
    ' Delete this if you don't want the MsgBox to show
    'MsgBox("Local folder doesn't exists, creating...")

    ' Create folder
    'MsgBox("C:\" + splitString(2) + "\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile")
    FSO.CreateFolder(Path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin")
End If
'All folders created, if non-existent

'Check to see if the files already exists in the destination folder

If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile1) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes And 1 Then 
            'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile1, DestinationPath, True
        Else 
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes - 1
            'Replace the file
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile1, DestinationPath, True
            'Reapply the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile1, DestinationPath, True
    End If
If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile2) Then
        'Check to see if the file is read-only
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile2).Attributes And 1 Then 
            'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile2, DestinationPath, True
        Else 
            'The file exists and is read-only.
            'Remove the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile2).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile2).Attributes - 1
            'Replace the file
            fso.CopyFile SourceFile2, DestinationPath, True
            'Reapply the read-only attribute
            fso.GetFile(DestinationFile2).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile2).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile2, DestinationPath, True
    End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Now, when I run it, I get an error: Bad file name or Number.

Points to note:

1. The folder structure gets created fine
2. Error copy for the copyfile tasks.

Comment: There is something off with your variable 'path'. With the destination files you always append C:\users at the beginning , but later on when the folders are created you don't. You didn't say where it comes from so I am not 100% sure but I guess as the folders are created the latter one is the correct use.

Comment: The error that comes up is with the line:

fso.CopyFile SourceFile1, DestinationPath, True (Line: 103, Char: 9)

The error is: Bad file name or number.

Both files are placed in the same directory as the script and names are noted absolutely correctly. Please help.

Comment: String concatenation operator is the ampersand (`&`), not `+`. Better yet, use [`fso.BuildPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to create your paths. `WScript.Echo` the paths to see what you're creating.

Comment: Thanks, but the path is being created fine. I agree it will make the script shorter, however the issue is with the copyfile command, not the path. Even if I use + instead of & I get the same error. I tried this:

DestinationPath = ("C:\Users" + path + "\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\adobeconnectaddin")

Comment: To answer JBP's question: Yes, it first checks and creates the complete folder structure, then attempts to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your path is simply not yet set when you create the destinationFile1 and destinationFile2.

have you tried setting the path before those two?

Comment: Yes, it first checks and creates the complete folder structure, then attempts to copy the files. Can you please check the complete script and help? I really need to get this going ASAP.

Comment: okay, I'm not entirely sure, but getfile.attribute is supposed to return a value, 1 or 0. right? if that is the case, then `If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes And 1 Then ` seems to be asking something wrong. i think it should be `If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile1).Attributes = 1 Then `